# cross compiling openssl with specific version of glibc for embedded system

Tags: openssl, glibc, fips

I am trying to compile Openssl in fips mode. I have compile the fips module/canister and I use that when I compile openssl. Everything seems to work but everything breaks down when I move the openssl binary onto the target platform (arm) it complains that it does not have the correct version of glibc, because the version of glibc on the target platform (arm) is 2.12.2 but the version of glibc on the building host (i386 ubuntu) is 2.15. I can manually add a newer version of glibc to the embedded target platform and then openssl will work but then other parts of the embedded linux system break because of the different glibc.

I need to be able to compile openssl against the exact version 2.12.2 version of glibc so when I move it to the target it still works.

```
~ # openssl version
openssl: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by openssl)
```

this is my compile code that I run on the host

```
make clean
export TARGETMACH=arm-none-linux-gnueabi
export BUILDMACH=i686-pc-linux-gnu
export CROSS=arm-linux
export TOOLCHAIN_DIR=/usr/local/DigiEL-5.9/x-tools/arm-cortex_a8-liunx-gnueabi/
export PATH=/usr/local/DigiEL-5.9/x-tools/arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabi/bin/:$PATH
export MACHINE=armv71
export RELEASE=3.2.0
export SYSTEM=Linux
export ARCH=arm
export CROSS_COMPILE="arm-linux-gnueabi-" 
export FIPS_SIG=$PWD/util/incore
export HOSTCC=gcc
export CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/ssl-1.0.2/include"
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/DigiEL-5.9/x-tools/arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabi/arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabi/lib -R/usr/local/DigiEL-5.9/x-tools/arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabi/arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabi/lib"
export FIPSDIR=/home/autosol/CMApps/AppsWeCompile/fipsOpenSSL/install/

./config fips shared --openssldir=/home/autosol/CMApps/AppsWeCompile/compiledApps/openssl/usr --with-fipsdir=/home/autosol/CMApps/AppsWeCompile/fipsOpenSSL/install
make depend
make
make install
```

I have tried no-shared that does not help, but does create a much larger binary. I have tried setting ld_library and that causes seg fault.

~ # LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/mnt/mtd6part/free/lib/ openssl
Segmentation fault

ANY suggestions are welcome !

Answer (score 0):

Finally found out what it was. I had two different cross compilers on my build system one that some things were compiled against and another newer one that openssl was compiled against. So the new one had lib 2.15 and the old 2.12.2 of glibc. Best to just search your system for libc- and you will see if you have another version floating around.

I deleted the newer version and also found I had to update my config options

there was a big difference in
export CROSS_COMPILE="arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabi-"
before config, this tells it to use the binaries in the digi dir where the old option
export CROSS_COMPILE="arm-linux-gnueabi-"
told it to use the new cross compiler

maybe that will help someone.